# Passing a Jquery variable to use in a PHP script

Tags: php, jquery

I know I've asked this question before but I still need help with this, basically:

I have a booking grid as shown below which is on bookings.php

[image]

On this booking grid I have a dblClick event:

```
    ondblClickRow: function(rowid)
    {

        rowData = $("#bookings").getRowData(rowid);
        var brData = rowData['bookref'];

        getGridRow(brData);

        $("#cp-bookings-dialog").dialog({ hide: 'slide', height: 625, width: 733, title: 'Booking Reference: - '+ brData});
    },
```

This also opens a Jquery Dialog window on bookings.php:

```
<div class="cp-tiles-wrapper-dlg">

<div class="cp-booking-info left">

<p class="pno-margin">Booking Date: &nbsp;<strong>Booking Reference is = <? echo BookingDocket::get_bookref(); ?></strong></p>
<p class="pno-margin">Return Date: &nbsp;<strong><? echo BookingDocket::get_bookdate(); ?></strong></p>
<p class="pno-margin">Journey: &nbsp;<strong></strong></p>
<p class="pno-margin">Passenger Tel: &nbsp;<strong></strong></p>
<p class="pno-margin">E-mail: &nbsp;<strong></strong></p>

</div>

</div>
```

Where brData is the 'Booking Reference' value that I want to use in my PHP script. At the moment this dblClick event is being sent to the following Ajax request:

```
function getGridRow(brData) {

   $.ajax({

    url: 'scripts/php/bootstrp/all.request.php',
    type: 'POST',

    data: {

        fnme: 'getDGRow',
        rowdata: brData,

        id: null,
        condition: null
    },
    dataType: 'text/xml',
    timeout: 20000,
    error: function(){
        alert("It failed");
        $('#cp-div-error').html('');
        $('#cp-div-error').append('<p>There was an error inserting the data, please try again later.</p>');
        $('#cp-div-error').dialog('open');
    },
    success: function(response){

        // Refresh page

        //response = brData;
        //alert(response); <-- This alerts the correct Booking Reference value

    }
});
```

Which gets sent to all.request.php

```
// Switch to determine method to call
switch ($_REQUEST['fnme']) {

case 'getDGRow':
header('Content-type: text/xml');
GetBookings::getGridRow($_REQUEST['rowdata']);
break;
```

And finally to the PHP script where I want to use this Jquery value:

```
class GetBookings {

public static function getGridRow($rowdata) {

$pdo = new SQL();
$dbh = $pdo->connect(Database::$serverIP, Database::$serverPort, Database::$dbName, Database::$user, Database::$pass);

try {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblbookings WHERE bookref = '$rowdata'";

    //echo $query; <-- this passes the correct Booking Reference to £rowdata

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

    $stmt->execute();

    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

       BookingDocket::set_id($row['id']);
       BookingDocket::set_bookref($row['bookref']);
       BookingDocket::set_bookdate($row['bookingdate']);
       BookingDocket::set_returndate($row['returndate']);
       BookingDocket::set_journeytype($row['journeytype']);
       BookingDocket::set_passtel($row['passengertel']);
       BookingDocket::set_returndate($row['returndate']);



    $stmt->closeCursor();

}

catch (PDOException $pe) {
    die("Error: " .$pe->getMessage(). " Query: ".$stmt->queryString);
}

$dbh = null;

    }


}
?>
```

I'm not sure why, but this doesn't seem to be working. Basically at the time when the Jquery Dialog window is opened, `$rowdata` is null, but when I echo the query, it shows that `$rowdata` has the correct value.

I have tried putting the code for the jquery window into a seperate php file and in the sucess ajax script I have added the following:

```
        $('#cp-bookings-dialog').load('bookings-dialog.php', function() {
           alert('Load was performed.');
        });
```

but this doesn't make any difference. I know all the code is correct because if I set $rowdata to 'BR12345' for example, it displays the values I need in the jquery booking dialog. What I believe needs to be done is for the PHP query to run after the value `$rowdata` has been passed to the PHP script.

Anybody got any idea of how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a JSON encoded object from your PHP script to use in your pop up. Your echo call is evaluated before the AJAX call is made, and worse, it does not know about `GetBookings` state at all (the state is only valid for a single request).

And why is everying `static`? That looks like a bad software design.